# How do you verify an API request came from a certain domain?

Tags: php, api, dns, verification

I have a web API that I want to allow **any domain** to submit data to. However, to keep bogus spam down I want to find some way to insure that a request stating it's from *a certain domain actually is from that domain* and that someone isn't trying to trick me by posting on another domains behalf.

For example, if http://example.com submits some data - thats good. If script kiddie #237 submits data claiming to be example.com - that's bad.

At first I was going to use a secret key system to HMAC sign each request - but signup is going to be open, free, and automated for this API. I'm not sure how I could tell if PersonA or PersonB really owns http://example.com and deserves the API key.

Comment: Distribute API key which ties to a domain. You then check just the key and make sure the request originates from a valid domain. Your key would have to be a salted hash of the domain the key is valid for. Just my $0.02.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide **a key file** that they will have to upload on that domain. And you check the existence and valid data against your internal database.

Comment: Great idea, I forgot about this but even Google uses this approach. I would be nice though if there was some answer that didn't involve making HTTP requests to verify though. Maybe someday. http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto.html